# Extract ORMLite Database documentation and schema

Tags: database, database-schema, ormlite, eer-model

Is there any way to view the ORMLite Database as schema and maybe a documentation for it with all the tables and columns? Or maybe can I do it with SQLite?

Edit:
I need to make a documentation about the database from my application, so is there are chance I can extract it directly from ORMLite, the relationships, attributes or the EER Model to make a printscreen?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you rephrase this question?  Right now it is difficult to understand what you are talking about.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. I need to make a documentation about the database from my application, so is there are chance I can extract it directly from ORMLite, the relationships, attributes or the EER Model to make a printscreen?

Comment: Please edit the question and provide those details.